# Get first level li from ul with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried multiple ways to get the first level `<li>` elements but i couldn´t find the correct way.

I´ve tried:

```
for item in soup_inicio.find_all('div',{'class':'menu'}):
    sub_items = item.find_all('li', {'class':'categories'})
    for sub_item in sub_items:
        print(sub_item.text)
```

This is what i´m trying to scrape:

```html
<div class = 'menu'>
      <ul class = 'navigation' id = "news_ul">
        <li class = 'categories'> A </li>
          <ul>
            <li class = 'categories'> A1 </li>
            <li class = 'categories'> A2 </li>
            <li class = 'categories'> A3 </li>
          </ul>
        <li class = 'categories'> B </li>
          <ul>
            <li class = 'categories'> B1 </li>
          </ul>
        <li class = 'categories'> C </li>
          <ul>
            <li class = 'categories'> C1 </li>
            <li class = 'categories'> C2 </li>
          </ul>
        <li class = 'categories'> D </li>
          <ul>
            <li class = 'categories'> D1 </li>
          </ul>
```

This gives me all `<li>` elements (A,A1,A2,A3,B,B1,C,C1,C2,D,D1)

I would like to get only elements

```
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
<li>D</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`recursive`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) argument set to `False`:

```
soup_inicio \
 .find('div',{'class':'menu'}) \
 .find('ul', {'class': 'navigation'}) \
 .find_all('li', recursive=False)
```

this returns:

```
[<li class="categories"> A </li>,
 <li class="categories"> B </li>,
 <li class="categories"> C </li>,
 <li class="categories"> D </li>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `>` can do this:

```
lis = soup.select('#news_ul > li')
for li in lis:
    print(li)

##<li class="categories"> A </li>
##<li class="categories"> B </li>
##<li class="categories"> C </li>
##<li class="categories"> D </li>
```